# PHPMailer - how can I add break lines in altbody?

Tags: php, phpmailer, break, lines

How can I add break lines?

I'm using this:

```
$mailbody=$username."\r\n";
$mailbody.=$email."\r\n";

$altbody=$username."\r\n";
$altbody.=$email."\r\n";
```

But break lines are *not* there.

I'm using `$altbody` because for some reason the software I use to receive the emails does not read HTML, only plain text, so, `$altbody` is the body when the email reader does not support HTML, so, I can't use BR neither...

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11):

normally linebreaks with only `\n` should work in plain text emails.
but stick to the `<br/>`s in your html-mail `$mailbody`.

Comment: I can't use <br/> in a non-html mailer and for some reason it removes the \r and \n

Comment: Late to the party. I had the same problem. The \n's were stripped because there was a msgHTML() after setting the AltBody, msgHTML recreates the AltBody. Fixed by first calling msgHTML() and afterwards setting the AltBody.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have code earlier on that formats the message body? You may inadvertently be stripping out all html tags and all \ (e.g. if you use stripslashes).

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue when I sent an email with text from an HTML `textarea`. Solved it by using php `nl2br`.

Answer (score 0):

With PHPMailer you need to use the entire include entire `<html>` block.  Try this:

```
$msg = "<html><body>
Type your messsage here.<br><br>
Sincerely,<br>
<br>
Contributor
</body></html>";
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try [`heredoc`](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) like as

```
$altbody = <<<MAIL
Hello $username,

Welcome to example.com!
MAIL;
```

or

```
$altbody = <<<MAIL
Hello $username,\nWelcome to example.com!
MAIL;
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
$text  = $sender_name."<br>";
$text .=$reply_to_email."<br>";
$text .= $Mobile_No."<br>";
$text .= $message."<br>";
```

Comment: This has 1 missing start quote

Comment: The OP explicitly says they cannot use `<br>` tags because their software does not support HTML.

Answer (score 0):

This does not directly answer the question asked, but it does answer the question that led me to this post (and i cant leave a comment yet):

I used single quotes, but PHP interprets single and double quotes in a different manner.

Try using double quotes for the AltBody like `"\n"` and not `'\n'`.